# How to remove first element of an array using loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have very little experience with **PHP**, but I'm taking a class that has **PHP** review exercises.  One of them is to create a function that uses a loop to return all values of an array except the first value in an `unordered` list.  I'm assuming there's a way to do this using a `foreach` loop but cannot figure out how.  This is what I had but I feel like I am far off:

```
<?php    
$array = array('myName' => 'Becca', 'favColor' => 'violet', 'favMovie' => 'Empire Strikes Back', 'favBook' => 'Lullaby', 'favWeb' => 'twitter.com');

$myName = $array['myName'];
$favColor = $array['favColor'];
$favMovie = $array['favMovie'];
$favBook = $array['favBook'];
$favWeb = $array['favWeb'];

echo '<h1>' . $myName . '</h1>';

function my_function() {
foreach($array == $myName){
   echo '<ul>'
   . '<li>' . $favColor . '</li>'
   . '<li>' . $favMovie . '</li>'
   . '<li>' . $favBook . '</li>'
   . '<li>' . $favWeb . '</li>'

   . '</ul>';
 }
}

my_function();
 ?>
```

Comment: could you post your error/output ?

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ')'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to following

```
<?php    
      $array = array('myName' => 'Becca', 'favColor' => 'violet', 'favMovie' => 'Empire Strikes Back', 'favBook' => 'Lullaby', 'favWeb' => 'twitter.com');

$myName = $array['myName'];

echo '<h1>' . $myName . '</h1>';

 function my_function($array)
    {
       $count = 0;
       echo "<ul>";
       foreach($array as $key => $value)
       {
           if($key != "myName")
           {
               echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
           }

        }
        echo "</ul>"; 



    }    


my_function($array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This definitely helped.  I ended up doing the function/loop part a little differently: function myFunction($array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($key != "name") {
     echo "<li>" . $value . "</li>";

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
```

instead of

```
foreach($array == $myName){
```

> function that uses a loop to return all values of an array except the
>   first value

I'm not sure, what exactly you mean by except the first value. If you are trying to remove first element from the array. Then you could have used **[`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)**

If you are supposed to use loop then

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
   if ($count!=0)
   {
     // your code
   } 
   $count++;
}
```

Comment: This is not really answer of this question. Yes this is one of the problem, but not an answer.

Comment: @Pedram I'm yet to update answer. Also, please note, I answered as per currently available info.

Comment: Also mention this, can't use `$array` inside a `function` without `global`

Comment: @Pedram I have no objection, if you update my answer until, it is valid. ;-)

Comment: This can't be an edit, it just a note, I would not prefer to edit people's answer for such reason :) It's kinda reply.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi !  This definitely helped clarify and I was able to get it to work how I needed.

Comment: @bexter Then, you should have selected as accepted answer. :P